# queryCache.setQueryData is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I don't know if the creators of `react-query` have updated the library but , I can't seem to be able to access `setQueryData` from `queryCache`  nor can I import `queryCache` from  `react-query` .

I looked at the docs and it looks like its `queryCache` that is now importable from `react-query`   , and this is how its used  :

```
import {QueryCache,useMutation} from  "react-query" 

const queryCache= new QueryCache({
    onError:err=>console.log(err)
})

//but now thsi only has these 4 functions 
//queryCache.find
//queryCache.findAll
//queryCache.subscribe
//queryCache.clear
```

is these something I'm missing here because I've been following some tutorials and they're using `setQueryData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you've probably migrated to v3, which is a major version change
- in v3, you'll interact with the QueryCache via the `QueryClient`
- There is no global cache to import anymore - the recommended way is to call the `useQueryClient` hook, or to export the client that you created yourselves.

Please have a look at the extensive migration guide: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/migrating-to-react-query-3

all the examples and docs also use v3, so this should get you going.

Comment: thanks a lot I figured it was a major version change but had no idea how to migrate  ,they probably should include a versions dropdown in their docs site's navbar

Comment: there is a link to the v2 docs directly on the starting page, it links to: https://react-query-v2.tanstack.com/docs/overview